# Htaccess Rewrite to get Values after slash

Tags: .htaccess, web, config

I have seen many websites using /main/help/this_help/2
how could i write htaccess to fetch values after / and doesnt look for new directory? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule .*  http://mydomain.com/getvals.php?key1=%1&key2=%2&key3=%3&key4=%4   [L]
```

What it does, is to map this URI:

`http://mydomain.com/val1/val2/val3/val4`  where val1, val2, val3 and val4 don't exist.

To this resource:

`http://mydomain.com/getvals.php?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=val4` showing the previous URI in the browser's address bar.

If you want the mapped URI to be shown instead, add the flag `R`, like this `[R=301,L]`

In the script `getvals.php` the values are fetched. Example in PHP:

```
$Val1 = $_GET['key1'];
...
```

Hope this is the information you are looking for.